# Visual Studio 'Produce Single File' publish - Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog, .net-5

I have a .net5.0 console app using Serilog via the...

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                .CreateLogger();
```

All working fine in dev. When I publish using "Produce single file", the app works, but the logging doesn't.
I am logging to file and console... I see neither.

If I publish without using the single file, the logging works OK.

At first I thought it was an issue with reading the appsettings.json, but some simple Console.Writeline confirms the appsettings file is being read OK (at least from the app itself, can I confirm any way that Serilog is reading it OK?)

Comment: You should probably show relevant portion of `.csproj` file for Serilog. Might be how you're referencing...

Comment: Also please show your app.settings.json file. It matters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few issues with NET5 single file applications with Serilog due to the way NET5 bundles/extracts compared to the way that 3.x did.

First, [per the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#net-50-single-file-applications) for the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` library (bolding and code blocks mine):

> Currently, auto-discovery of configuration assemblies **is not supported
> in bundled mode**. Use `Using` section for workaround.

This means your appsettings.json file needs to look like the following (assuming you are using the Console and File sinks):

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "Logs/log.txt" } }
    ],
    // remaining config
  }
}
```

Now depending on which version of `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` you are using, you **may** need this workaround as well:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .ReadFrom.Configuration(config, "Serilog", ConfigurationAssemblySource.AlwaysScanDllFiles)
                  .CreateLogger();
```

*Instead*, you can also revert to [netcore3's bundling behavior](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/d455a60/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md#optional-settings) by modifying your project file as follows:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
 <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: As a friendly reminder, don't forget to check github when you have issues with open source libraries. There were at least two issues in the project with titles containing text directly from your title/question and usually the project maintainers are the best people to ask! Though... I just happened to have had this exact issue during my migration so already knew where to look

Comment: The "Using" in the appsettings did the trick pinkfloydx33. Thanks for the help, and i take on board your comment about the github resources. Many thanks.